# An inequality consequence of Berry-Esseen's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi$ be the cumulative distribution function of the standard gaussian random variable and let $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables $E[X_i]=\mu, Var[X_i]=\sigma^2$. Then call $Z_n = \frac{(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i)/n-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}.$

Now if $Z_n$ has bounded third moment, Berry-Esseen's inequality tells us that $$\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |P(Z_n\le x)-\Phi(x)|\le \frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}$$ where $k$ is some real constant. Then apparently we have for a real number $c$ that $$P(|Z_n|\ge c) \le 2(1-\Phi(c))+2\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ I think the term $2(1-\Phi(c))$ would be the result if $Z_n$ was $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and the second term is the correction term because it is not (because $n<\infty$). But other than that I am not sure how to derive the above (second) inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|Z_n|\ge c)&=\mathsf{P}(Z_n\le -c)+\mathsf{P}(Z_n\ge c) \\
&\le \Phi(-c)+(1-\Phi(c))+2k/\sqrt{n} \\
&=2(1-\Phi(c))+2k/\sqrt{n}.
\end{align}